# Trying to make a div appear when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code , first of all why is the div showing up when I set it's display value to "none"; and is there anythign I else I need to fix to make the div appear when I click the button?
Thanks

HTML

```
<button onclick="openTest()">Try it</button>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display ="none";

function openTest() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SnubbenGuden/6092dquv/4/

Comment: your function isn't being called. Add an event listiner to the div in javascript.

Comment: For all the questions you've asked on this site, please have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Don't use inline javascript - attach an event listener instead and make sure to place your code either in `window.onload = function() {}` or right before the closing `</body>` tag. That way your elements will be found when the script runs. [**Try this code**](https://jsfiddle.net/6092dquv/5/):

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Try it</button>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display ="none";

function openTest() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', openTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [mmm already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35853247/1452922), the main problem is the order of execution of your fiddle and, possibly, your real code.

Basically the HTML was parsed before the JS executed, so first of all, `openTest` was not found yet. Then, when your JS is parsed, `openTest` is defined, but it is likely that your code is actually wrapped in a function to not leak globals. In the result, `openTest` is not accessible again.

Fixing it could be as simple as that: https://jsfiddle.net/6092dquv/18/ - exposing the `openTest` function explicitly binding it to the global `window` object by changing 

`function openTest() {`
 
to 

`window.openTest = function() {`

But it is a bad practice, you leak a global and you mix presentation and logic (HTML and JS) in your HTML.

So the good pratice is as in the aforementioned answer: grab your button, assign the handler, and do your logic in one place - in JS. If possible, the button should be a regular form handled server-side if the user doesn't have JS (it doesn't mean he disabled it - it means, for example, the JS file is still loading for him!), or if that's not an option, insert the button programatically from JS as well, so he never sees a thing that doesn't work.